# SAP UI5 JQuery drag and drop is not working

Tags: jquery, sapui5, drag

I have created drag and drop functionality in sap ui5 app as mentioned [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/08/21/how-to-use-drag-and-drop-between-two-sapui5-ui-elements/).

1) when working with single view & controller, drag and drop functionality is working fine. 
2) when working with multiple view and controller, if my drag & drop view is not my initial view. drag and drop functionality is not working.

1) I have tried to load the libraries at controller level and component level.
it is working fine when there is only one view and controller.
2) but the same is not working when there are multiple views and controllers, majorly when I am navigating to the drag drop screen from other screen. If drag and drop view is the initial view, then also it is working fine.

1)at controller level & component level I have written like below in both the cases

```
jQuery.sap.require("DragNDropDragNDrop.model.widget");
jQuery.sap.require("DragNDropDragNDrop.model.mouse");
jQuery.sap.require("DragNDropDragNDrop.model.sortable");
jQuery.sap.require("DragNDropDragNDrop.model.droppable");
jQuery.sap.require("DragNDropDragNDrop.model.draggable");
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    'sap/m/MessageBox'
```

Comment: that blog is *really* old

Comment: would you please suggest any other :)

Comment: @vikram Generally, I'd suggest to avoid blogs altogether but try understanding official docu and samples instead, as UI5 is constantly evolving but blog posts not.

Comment: I understand the problem, but not yours because your input is a little ... ;) What I can say is, that drag and drop works on multiple view / xml fragment dialogs etc. why it is not working for you is not apparent at the moment...

Comment: It is working, it was dom element reference issue. Thanks to everyone.